# Removing suffixes from variable names in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set that I'm trying to simply rename a lot of variables in. The variable names are structured in this way:

```
'2018 10 20 ABC'n
'2018 10 27 ABC'n
'2018 11 03 ABC'n
```

and so on. So it's a new variable once a week and I would simply like to remove the ABC from all variable names. But there are many and I would like the solution to be general so I don't have to type

```
rename '2018 10 20 ABC'n='2018 10 20'n
```

for every instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax for directly renaming variables according to a complex name transformation.  You will have to generate source code (codegen) for doing the `rename` statements you identified.

Example:

Use `Proc CONTENTS` to get the names of the variables as data and `Proc SQL` to compute the *oldname=newname* pairs needed by a `rename` statement.   Modify the data set metadata in place using `Proc DATASETS`.

```
options validvarname=any;

data have;
  attrib
    x y z p q r
    '2018 10 20 ABC'n
    '2018 10 27 ABC'n
    '2018 11 03 ABC'n
    length = 8
  ;
run;

proc contents noprint data=have out=have_metadata(keep=name);
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select quote(name,"'") || 'n = ' || quote(tranwrd(name,'ABC',''),"'") || 'n'
  into :renames separated by ' '
  from have_metadata
  where upcase(name) like '%ABC'
  ;

proc datasets nolist lib=work;
  modify have;
  rename &renames;
run;
quit;
```

Should log

```
197  proc datasets nolist lib=work;
198    modify have;
199    rename &renames;
NOTE: Renaming variable '2018 10 20 ABC'n to '2018 10 20'n.
NOTE: Renaming variable '2018 10 27 ABC'n to '2018 10 27'n.
NOTE: Renaming variable '2018 11 03 ABC'n to '2018 11 03'n.
200  run;

NOTE: MODIFY was successful for WORK.HAVE.DATA.
```